# Using countifs with more than one condition using references not values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010

Am trying to apply the countifs function to two columns of my data sheet with two different conditions to meet (one for each column) using cell references in the criteria. The following syntax has worked several times before, but am not getting the result I expect after manually counting the cells that meet both criteria this time

I8=COUNTIFS('MR Follow up'!$H:$H;"PO";'MR Follow up'!$N:$N;"<="&I4)

[image]

Any ideas on why is this happening? Could it be because am selecting a range of a different sheet? (Excels description of the function allows to do this). I also came up with the idea that maybe it doesn't counts duplicated values (in my columns I have rows with same values on both tested fields that meet criteria)

[image]
[image]

Comment: `not getting the result I expect` OK, what *are* you getting? If you make a dummy sheet with only a few rows of data, does the formula work there? What do you get when you use "Evaluate Formula" on the Formula ribbon?

Comment: After reviewing the columns am almost sure that the problem is that excel is not counting the times both criteria are met if it had happened before and the cells value are the same

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks, after extracting a piece of the data in a new worksheet and trying to the same it's still happening and it confirms the fact that it doesn't count if the conditions have been met before with rows with the same values in the criteria range.

Comment: @EngineerToast Am getting a smaller number that the actual count of rows that meet the criteria.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data & formula showing both what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: I have added an screenshot to the initial post.

Comment: Please include the column/rows in you screenshot so we can tell what cells the formula refers to. I suspect you may need to change `"&I4)` to `"&$I$4)`

Comment: Sorry hahaha new in this kind of forums, will do that.

Comment: I [recreated your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnMcm.png) from the screenshot and I got a value of `8`. That leads me to believe that the data in my sheet doesn't match the data in your sheet. Check that none of the "PO" data has extra spaces in the cell and the dates are all the year that you expect and not 3023 or something. You could even throw in a check for each cell like `=L11="PO"` and `=M11<=DATE(2023,8,25)`. Dig into the data to find what's different.

Comment: I will do that, thanks. Anyways why would you get 8 and not 9 when all columns meet the both criteria?

Comment: I made an search and replace in the PO column to have exactly the same string in all rows, but it still doesn't come out with the expected value (9).

Comment: `31-Aug-23 > 25/08/2023` so the expected result should be 8.

Comment: True, sorry about that again hahaha. After seeing that I set the criteria date to a larger number (31/08/2023) and now it counts 8. After that I augmented the value to 30/09/2023 (a much larger date) and now it counts 9. Now my guess is that the function doesn't understand right the "<=" operator. I will upload a photo of both escenarios.

Comment: Or the value is not just a date, but also includes time (which you don't see if the value is formatted as a date)

Comment: The countifs function can apply multiple ranges and criteria, and count the number of times all criteria are met. You need to make sure that each additional range has the same number of rows and columns as the first range. You can also use wildcard characters (question mark and asterisk) to match any character or sequence of character https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842